# local stream microphone not working while share screen + system audio shared in HTML JS

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, webrtc, peerjs

[See image still implement but not working ✅](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDXwr.png)

[Here is code HTML + JS ✅]

```
  function startScreenShare() {
        if (screenSharing) {
            stopScreenSharing()
        }
        navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(
            { video: { mediaSource: "screen" }, audio: true }
        ).then((stream) => {
            setScreenSharingStream(stream);
    
            screenStream = stream;
            let videoTrack = screenStream.getAudioTracks()[0];
            videoTrack.onended = () => {
                stopScreenSharing()
            }
            if (peer) {
                let sender = currentPeer.peerConnection.getSenders().find(function (s) {
                    return s.track.kind == videoTrack.kind;
                })
                sender.replaceTrack(videoTrack)
                screenSharing = true
            }
            console.log(screenStream)
        })
    }
```

We have tried to share screen audio. When sharing the **screen**, **microphone** and **screen-sharing** audio do not work together. **Mic** does not work when system audio is on. System audio does **not working** if end mic is on. please explain me what is the about **issue**.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: resolved please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76759709/15175667