# microphone not working while share screen + system audio shared using peerjs webrtc

Tags: webrtc, multipeer-connectivity, peerjs, openwebrtc

[image: Screenshot 2023-07-19 182435]

We have tried to **share screen** audio. When sharing the screen, microphone and screen-sharing audio do not work together. Mic does not work when **system audio** is on. System audio does **not working** if end mic is on. please explain me what is the about issue.

Here is code:

```
function startScreenShare() {
    if (screenSharing) {
        stopScreenSharing()
    }
    navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia(
        { video: { mediaSource: "screen" }, audio: true }
    ).then((stream) => {
        setScreenSharingStream(stream);

        screenStream = stream;
        let videoTrack = screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0];
        videoTrack.onended = () => {
            console.log('Hiii')
            stopScreenSharing()
        }
        if (peer) {
            let sender = currentPeer.peerConnection.getSenders().find(function (s) {
                return s.track.kind == videoTrack.kind;
            })
            sender.replaceTrack(videoTrack)
            screenSharing = true
        }
        console.log(screenStream)
    })
}
```

We have tried to share screen audio. When sharing the screen, microphone and screen-sharing audio do not work together. Mic does not work when system audio is on. System audio does not working if end mic is on.

**I want mic and system audio to play along with share screen.**

Comment: Please add the relevant PHP code *or* remove any unrelated tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Re-Solved**:

```
const audioStream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true });

audioStream.getAudioTracks().forEach((track) => {
            screenStream1.addTrack(track);
});

const screenStream1 = await navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({
            video: {
                cursor: "always"
            },
            audio: {
                echoCancellation: true,
                noiseSuppression: true,
                sampleRate: 44100
            }
 });


async function mergeTracks(audioStream, screenStream1) {
    const audioContext = new AudioContext();
    const audioStreamTwo = new MediaStream()
    audioStreamTwo.addTrack(screenStream1.getAudioTracks()[0])
    baseSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStream);
    extraSource = audioContext.createMediaStreamSource(audioStreamTwo);
   
    const dest = audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();

    var baseGain = audioContext.createGain();
    var extraGain = audioContext.createGain();
    baseGain.gain.value = 0.8;
    extraGain.gain.value = 0.8;
    baseSource.connect(baseGain).connect(dest);
    extraSource.connect(extraGain).connect(dest);

    baseSource.connect(dest);
    extraSource.connect(dest);

    return dest.stream;

}


  var screenStream = screenStream1;
  Stream = await mergeTracks(audioStream, screenStream); //FUNCTION

console.log('currentPeer---------', currentPeer)
if (peer && currentPeer) {
    const videoTrack = screenStream.getVideoTracks()[0];

    const sender = currentPeer.peerConnection.getSenders().find((s) => s.track.kind === videoTrack.kind);
    sender.replaceTrack(videoTrack);

    const audioTrack = Stream.getAudioTracks()[0];
    const audioSender = currentPeer.peerConnection.getSenders().find((s) => s.track.kind === audioTrack.kind);
    audioSender.replaceTrack(audioTrack);

    screenSharing = true;
}
```